# Resorting and holding a vector

Tags: sorting, vector, modelica, openmodelica

So this is probably a very specific problem and i am not sure if it is even solvable but here we go:
I have a vector with 6 indices which each are variables. These variables get calculated separately. What I want now is that the order of the indices changes at a specific time and stays like that. But the actual value of the indices needs to keep being calculated. Maybe explaining it in my Modelica code helps with understanding.

I have a vector with six indices, made up out of 6 variables, let's name them A to F. A to F are each calculated in a different way which is (probably) not relevant here so I'm simply writing [...] for that here. They behave independently of each other.

```
Real Vector[6];
Real A;
Real B;
Real C;
Real D;
Real E;
Real F;

equation

A = 3*x;
B = 5-x +7/x ...;
C = [and so on]
D = [...]
E = [...];
F = [...];
```

Initially, the Vector is sorted like this:

```
Vector = {A, B, C, D, E, F};
```

But I want the order of the indices to be resorted via some if-clauses every 100 seconds (starting at time=0) which i make work like that:

```
when sample(0,100) then
Vector = {if xyz then A, 
          elseif xyz then B ....}
end when;
```

Again, the specific way in which i resort the indices (probably) doesn't matter because it definitely works.
My problem is: While it does *resort* my Vector every 100 seconds and holds this new order/sequence (which is exactly what i need), it of course also holds the calculated actual values of A to F at that time. Which means i get constant values between each time step.
What i **need** is the new order to hold but the values of A to F need to keep being calculated.

I also tried using *if* instead of *when* like

```
if time <100 then Vector = {A, B, C, D, E, F}
elseif time >=100 and <200 then Vector = {if xyz then A, elseif xyz then B ....(see above)}
else ...;
end if;
```

Problem here: it does also resort my Vector while also calculating A to F. But it looks to resort my vector all the time, not only once every 100 seconds --> holding the order until the next 100 seconds are over (the resorting is dependent on other calculated values in the model which are constantly changing).

My model is very huge so it's tricky to share all the parts that weave into this part of my work which is the reason i had to simplify my explanations as much as possible. I hope someone can help me with this.
I'm still relatively new at this and have been mostly teaching myself for the last few months so maybe I'm simply not aware of an easy obvious solution here. Or what I need is simply not doable in Modelica.
Thank you!

Comment: I would use integer variables a, b, c, d, e, f and Vector[a], Vector[b], Vector[c], Vector[d], Vector[e], Vector[f] instead of variables A, B, C, D, E, F and only change a, b, c, d, e, f each 200 seconds.

Comment: I couldn't understand your problem wholly but I believe you want to :1.Do not alter the way A, B, C.. are calculated 2. Sort the vector every 100 seconds. I would have approached to sort the indexes rather than index values A, B, C and reinitialize the vector within when clause.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure I got the question correctly, but would the the graph below show what you need?

[image: Simulation Result]
...with `v` being the original vector and `vs` being the continuously computed, but sorted (ascending every 100s) version of `v`.

This is the respective code:

```
model VectorSorting "Computes 'vs' every 100s from 'v' with acending order"
  Real A, B, C, D, E, F;  // Some variables computed in equations below
  Real v[6]; // vector for A...F
  Real vs[6]; // sorted version of 'v'
  Integer i[6](start=1:6, fixed=true); // indexes of vector
  Real d[6](start=zeros(6), fixed=true); // dummy variable

equation 
  A = time+200;
  B = time-150;
  C = 3*time-333;
  D = 0.5*time+75;
  E = -250;
  F = 750;

  v = {A, B, C, D, E, F};
  vs = v[i];

  when sample(0, 100) then
    (d, i) = Modelica.Math.Vectors.sort(v);
  end when;

  annotation (experiment(StopTime=500), uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end VectorSorting;
```